# How to implement the how far away feature with Core Location into an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

How do I add that feature that tells you how far away from something you are into an iPhone App?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [distanceFromLocation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html). It returns the distance (in meters) between the two locations.